# How can change/convert timezone when I query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I need a query to convert timezone in PostgreSQL

I have already tried this query

```
Select users.last_update_time + interval '7 hours'
```

And it plus for my result 7 hours.

But I have a problem that if I choose results from 31/01/2022 to 06/02/2022. It will include the result on 07/02/2022. Example before I plus 7 hours, it's on around 17:00 06/02/2022 to 00:00 07/02/2022.

The correct result has to be after +7 hours. So it means that result after plus 7 hours from 17:00 06/02/2022 to 00:00 07/02/2022 shouldn't be in there.

Comment: What data type is `last_update_time`?

Comment: i query this 

select pg_typeof(users.last_update_time)
From users

And it give result: timestamp without time zone

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29

Answer (score 1):

Then you should include the time zone in the query like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE tscol BETWEEN '2022-01-31 00:00:00 America/Vancouver'
                AND '2022-02-07 00:00:00 America/Vancouver';
```

If you don't want to hard code the time zone, the best thing is to set the `timezone` database parameter to the correct time zone in your database session. Then you can use a simple type cast, which will respect the setting:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE tscol BETWEEN CAST ('2022-01-31 00:00:00' AS timestamp with time zone)
                AND CAST ('2022-02-07 00:00:00' AS timestamp with time zone);
```

Comment: thank you so much for this.

But it will be a problem if I put this query in the dashboard. It will not be an automatic change result following the time I chosse because the clause is from 31/01 - 07/02.

Comment: I have added information how to avoid hard coding the time zone.